# How to define image dimension rule message in laravel

Tags: laravel, validation, lumen

I have the following image validation for my POST request and I am not quite sure how to add custom validation message specifically for `min_width`, `min_height` and `ratio`?

```
protected function getRules(): array
{
    return [
        'logo' => 'required|file|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png|dimensions:min_width=400,min_height=400,ratio=1/1'
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define your message like this:

```
'logo.dimensions' => 'The logo must be at least :min_width x :min_height pixels and have ratio :ratio',
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, its pretty close to what @ibrahem-Kamal answered. But this still doesn't tell what the exact validation issue is like any of the other laravel validations. There are 3 validations combined into 1. But I am going to upvote this because it atleast shows how to customize the attributes.

Answer (score 0):

```
        'logo.dimensions' => 'The logo must be at least 400 x 400 pixels!',
```

Comment: What about specific messages for `min_width`, `min_height`, `ratio`? If a user uploads `500x600`, I need to be specific that the `ratio` validation doesn't pass.

Comment: am not sure of this but i dont think they provide that , again not sure

Comment: @Abishek You can add `logo.ratio`, `logo.min_width`, etc. to the `messages` array your rule returns.

Answer (score -1):

Your validation:

`"logo"  => "dimensions:min_width=400,min_height=400"`

Your form, multipart/form-data:

`<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"></form>`